# How To Access Internal Private Variables Inside Static Methods C#

Tags: c#, mvvm, methods, model, static

I'm coding in MVVM and have a Calculation class. Inside this Calc Class I have different static Memberfunctions which each calculate a portion of my calculations.

E.g.:
Inside Calc Class:

one of the Memberfunctions:

```
public static double CalcTimeJerkAcc(double limitedAcceleration, double maxJerk)
{
    return (limitedAcceleration / maxJerk);
}
```

another Memberfunction in which I use timeJerkAcc:

```
public static double CalcCalculation(double timeJerkAcc, ...) { ... }
```

now I want to implement these Calculations into a Model:

```
public double PositioningTime
    {
        get
        {
             return CalcClassObject.CalcCalculation(CalcClassObject.timeJerkAcc, ...); 
        }
    }
```

How do I access private Variables such as "timeJerkAcc" from the Calc Class, despite them being static?
My approach with `CalcClassObject.timeJerkAcc` in the transfer parameters in `CalcClassObject.CalcCalculation(...)` is clearly wrong. 
I'm stuck. Can someone clear this problem up for me? I'm fairly new to C# and hope this is not a really dumb question...

It's hard to describe my problem well, but I hope someone will understand what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You question is not clear.  For example, where is the field `timeJerkAcc` defined?  You need to show all relevant code, in particular a [mcve].

Comment: `timeJerkAcc` is a variable inside the Calc Class, but because the Methode is static, it is never used. The question should rather be, how can I use the return value of `CalcTimeJerkAcc` inside `CalcCalculation` without giving the method a transfer paramter? Should I create a new Variable in `CalcCalculation` and write the return value on it?

Comment: Something inside `CalcCalculation` like: `var x = CalcTimeJerkAcc(limitedAcceleration, maxJerk);`

Comment: But then I'd have to give CalcTimeJerkAcc also transfer paramters. One from my Model object (limitedAcceleration) and one from another model object (maxJerk).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood right, but you want to create a model that calls static methods and variables.

So I created a small snippet that will hopefully help you:

This is the main Class:

```
class Solution
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyModel model = new MyModel();

        Console.WriteLine(model.PositioningTime);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

And the Calculation class:

```
public class Calculation
{
    public static double timeJerkAcc = 12;
    public static double maxJerk = 30;
    public static double CalcTimeJerkAcc(double limitedAcceleration, double maxJerk)
    {
        return limitedAcceleration / maxJerk;
    }

    public static double CalcCalculation(double timeJerkAcc, double temp)
    {
        return timeJerkAcc / temp;
    }
}
```

And finally, the Model class:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public double PositioningTime
    {
        get
        {
            return Calculation.CalcCalculation(Calculation.timeJerkAcc,Calculation.maxJerk);
        }
    }
}
```

To call static variables or methods that are outside of the current class, you have to set them as **public**.

Hope this helped you, if it didn't, please try to explain your problem with more details,

Regards.